# MySQL order by clause

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
    ORDER BY (CASE ADDRESS
    WHEN 'DELHI'     THEN 1
    WHEN 'BHOPAL'    THEN 2
    WHEN 'KOTA'      THEN 3
    WHEN 'AHMADABAD' THEN 4
    WHEN 'MP'   THEN 5
    ELSE 100 END) ASC, ADDRESS DESC;
```

what does that 100 mean?

Comment: how would we know about your **100**

Comment: I am getting same answer when I replaced 100 with 10, then what's the importance of that number ?

Answer (score 0):

`100` is the value which will be used if no `address` case is matched.

Comment: what if there are only 10 records in table and there are two or more records where no address case matched ?

Comment: @DevilHunter in that case, each of the unmatched records would be ordered by `100`. in this case, you'd likely want a second criteria to sort on to ensure that the sort is stable.

Answer (score 0):

All that `(CASE ADDRESS WHEN 'DELHI' THEN 1 WHEN 'BHOPAL' THEN 2 WHEN 'KOTA' THEN 3 WHEN 'AHMADABAD' THEN 4 WHEN 'MP' THEN 5 ELSE 100 END)` is used for order returned list by address, the logic of this is:

1. first go addresses - DELPHI (gets value 1)
2. second - BHOPAL  (gets value 2)
3. third - KOTA  (gets value 3)
4. fourth - AHMADABAD  (gets value 4)
5. fifth - MP  (gets value 5)
6. and then everything else (gets value 100)

And then all this list is ordered by those number `ASC`

Why `100`? Is just the number bigger then 5 (to go those addresses in end of the list), it will make no difference if it will be 6, 50 or 1000, it only have to be bigger than 5